# Use std::map with pointer

Tags: pointers, stl, c++-cli, clr

i try to use std::map as property in my class. I use Visual Studio 2012, and my class is like:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
    std::map<std::wstring,MyType> * mpMyMap;
    MyClass()
{
mpMyMap = new std::map<std::wstring,MyType>();
}
~MyClass()
{
delete mpMyMap;
}
Get(std::wstring name)
{
    return mpMyMap[name];
} 
}
```

At return mpMyMap[name]; I get error, what there is no operator[] for this type. What should I do?

Comment: Why is `mpMyMap` a pointer?  Do you need it to be a pointer (you probably _dont't_).  If you _do_ need it to be a pointer, you should use a smart pointer type to wrap it (like `std::unique_ptr`, or `boost::scoped_ptr`).

Comment: why std::map in C++/CLI? why not System::Collections::Generic::Dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

the bracket operator is on the map, not on the pointer of a map...

Try : return (*mpMyMap)[name];

Answer (score 1):

`mpMyMap` is a pointer (for which I can see no reason), so you need to dereference it:

```
return (*mpMyMap)[name];
```

If `mpMyMap` must be a dynamically allocated remember to `delete` it in the destructor and either prevent copying of `MyClass` or implement copy constructor and assignment operator.

Note `Get()` is missing a return type (which should be either `MyType` or `MyType&`). Make the argument to `Get()` a `const std::wstring&` to avoid unnecessary copying and `const` as `Get()` does not modify it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
MyType Get(std::wstring name)
{
    return (*mpMyMap)[name];
}
```

You could also make the map an instance member instead of a pointer

```
std::map<std::wstring,MyType> mMyMap;
```

then your original code in `Get` would work and you'd get rid of memory management in the constructor and the destructor of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
return (*mpMyMap)[name];
```

or

```
return mpMyMap->operator[]( name );
```

P.S. What is this

```
  public ref class MyClass
//^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, add return type for `Get` (`MyType` in your case)

Comment: It's not native C++, it's C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Since `mpMyMap` is pointer first variant is

```
Get(std::wstring name)
{
    return (*mpMyMap)[name];
}
```

And second

```
Get(std::wstring name)
{
    return mpMyMap->operator[](name);
}
```

And Get should have return-type.

Comment: You may have your parens misplaced. Shouldn't it be `(*mpMyMap)[name]`?

Comment: @Robᵩ yeah. Misprint. Thanks.